# Group concatenated strings by 160 characters per group and do the same thing on the remaining

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite

I have a table which I want the data to retrieved. I managed to retrieve these datas. The twist is I want to concatenate these data (which are of strings) to create a string with 160 characters. I managed to do this by having this code answered by a guy here in Stackoverflow.

The code is this:

```
List<Pending> pending = db.getAllPending();
    String a = "";
    for (Pending pn : pending) {
       if (a.length() + pn.getPm_str().length() <= 160) {
    a += pn.getPm_str();
    }
    else
    break;
    }
```

> The code concatenates the data until it has formed a 160 length string. It will disregard the other data which happened to exceed with the limit.

My problem is: how am I going to do the same thing for the remaining data from the list (which are not included in the first batch of 160 length string)? I also want these data to be concatenated to create the same.

The concept of the program has something to do with SMS sending. Data are concatenated and are group as one sms to be sent.

Need help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list of resulting strings and add to it when the concatenated string reaches the limit:

```
List<Pending> pending = db.getAllPending();
List<String> resultingStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
String a = "";
for (Pending pn : pending) {
   if (a.length() + pn.getPm_str().length() <= 160) {
        a += pn.getPm_str();
   }
   else {
        resultingStrings.add(a);
        a = pn.getPm_str();
   }
} 
resultingStrings.add(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
ArrayList<String> messageList=new ArrayList<>();

for (Pending pn : pending) {
  if (a.length() + pn.getPm_str().length() <= 160) {
   a += pn.getPm_str();
  }
  else{
   messageList.add(a);    
   a="";
   a += pn.getPm_str();
 }
}
messageList.add(a);
```